# Im trying to connect to a URL with Socket but can only connect by providing an IP Adress (Java android)

Tags: java, android, sockets, url, arduino

im working on an app that involves connecting to an Arduino based server.
I have a free DNS url that my arduino is running.
The app works fine when the code is written like this:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (!connected) {// if not connected yet

            try {// try to create a socket and outputstream
                socket = new Socket("0.0.0.0.0", 8080);// create a
                                                            // socket
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                        socket.getOutputStream());// and stream

                // connection status
                changeConnectionStatus(true);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {// catch and

                changeConnectionStatus(false);
            } catch (IOException e) {// catch and

                changeConnectionStatus(false);
            }
```

but it is not doing anything when I change the Socket line to this:

```
socket = new Socket("http://balblalbla.me", 8080);
```

Is this supposed to work?
If not please help on connecting to a url
thanks in advance

Comment: `0.0.0.0.0` is not a valid IP address to connect to.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `http://` portion and try again.  You need to specify just the hostname or IP address by itself, not a full URL.